# GCC linker error (cudaMemGetInfo) while using GPU Ocelot

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda

I'm using [GPU Ocelot](https://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/) in order to build CUDA programs since I don't have access to an NVIDIA GPU.  I'm compiling the sample code using `nvcc` and linking using `g++`.  I'm doing this since I need to link a C++ program against a static library built using `nvcc`.

Here are the commands I'm using:

```
$ nvcc -c cudaMemCheck.cu

$ g++ -o cudaMemCheck cudaMemCheck.o -locelot
```

This results in the following error:

```
cudaMemCheck.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_00006ca0_00000000-1_cudaMemCheck.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `cudaMemGetInfo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the following code in `cudaMemCheck.cu`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t free, total;

    cudaMemGetInfo(&free, &total);

    fprintf(stdout, "free = %zu | total = %zu\n", free, total);

    return 0;
}
```

Oddly enough, this method of compiling and linking seems to work if I link with `nvcc`.  The program I'm linking the CUDA library against is an MPI program that uses the `mpic++` wrapper for compilation, so I'm not sure I can use `nvcc` for linking.

Also I want to note that using `g++` to link source files that use other functions in the CUDA Runtime (e.g. `cudaMalloc`) seems to work just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error says that it doesn't know what `cudaMemGetInfo` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see for yourself [here](https://github.com/gtcasl/gpuocelot/blob/master/ocelot/ocelot/cuda/interface/CudaRuntimeInterface.h), the Ocelot developers never added  `cudaMemGetInfo` to their runtime implementation. `cudaMemGetInfo` was a relatively new addition to the runtime API (appeared in CUDA 4 IIRC), and Ocelot was most actively developed against CUDA 2 and CUDA 3.

You only two choices are to not use it, or add your own implementation (it could be an empty stub if you like) and link that.

Comment: Thanks!  Not sure how I didn't think to look that up.